# How to generate .exe drivers instead than .sys?

Tags: c, kernel, driver, mode

I'm new in kernel mode world. I've tried to write a simple "hello world" driver in a Windows 7 virtual machine, I'm using WDK 7600.16385.1 -> x86 Free Build Environment for compilation, when it does, the generated driver is a .sys file extension, so I'd like to know if is possible to set up the compiler to generate an .exe file, so thereby a user can run it by double-clicking the executable.

I thought that perhaps, when I install some driver and the "setup" is a .exe file, in fact it isn't really the driver, it is a program that installs the driver (in .sys extension) on your computer, so the .exe file is just the installer and not the driver itself. But I am not sure if this is true.

If you could give me some information about generating a driver for Windoes, I'll be eternally grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `driver` is used to communicate between hardware and the operating system, not to be double-clicked and run by the user, and a "Hello world" driver doesn't make sense. Perhaps you should learn a little more about what drivers are and how they're supposed to be used before you try to write one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `.exe` files you're looking at are, indeed, installers. There are a number of tools available for creating installers; [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) is one of the more popular options.

Answer (score 0):

`.exe` marks executable files for Windows user mode. The format of user mode and kernel mode "executables" differs a lot. In particular, there is no such thing as user running the kernel executible. Kernel drivers aren't directly accessible to user mode; communication is allowed only via OS-defined interfaces, i.e. user-mode component must perform a dedicated OS call which will be routed to the kernel component by the OS. There are many more differences between kernel and user modes but this particular one explains why running kernel driver by user isn't possible (and shouldn't be).

As for your second question, yes, these `.exe` files are installers.